# Is a way to implement a double index into a special method Python?

Tags: python, magic-methods

I am currently trying to implement a Sudoku solver where I have created a 9x9 board and a dictionary object sDict that contains all candidate sets for each position in the board. Before adding to the board I validate whether a value can be placed in a specific position using sDict. This works in the **ini** method as sDict updates its values when placing the initial inputs into the board.

However there is a problem concerning the **setitem** special method where it doesn't seem to work as I intend when providing two index values. It seems that the **setitem** method can only be called when using just one [] index and completely ignores my overridden method updating my board regardless when using two [][] indexes. Can anyone please explain why this is and if there is a better solution than just switching to a single index?

setitem code below:

```
    def __setitem__(self,index1, index2 value):
    if self.validate((index1,index2), value): # somehow getting through the check
        self.board[index1][index2] = value
    else:
        ValueError("Value '%d' is not a valid input for this position" %value)
```

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: Look up [numpy](https://numpy.org/)

Comment: Yes, this is perfect! Thanks :)